# PNP-PowerShell: Get items based on CreatedBy

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I want to **get all items(documents or list items)** from **SharePoint Online site** **and its sub sites** based on createdBy using PnP-Powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a PnP Powershell script that will iterate through the lists and libraries of the site and for each list use the **Get-PnPListItem** command with a Camlquery to get the data based on Author field
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps